# Using npm-install in a yocto recipe

Tags: node.js, npm-install, yocto, recipe

I build a project for a x86 architecture with yocto sumo (2.5). I need now the support for NodeJs in version 10.15.1. I wrote a new recipe where I use the precompiled NodeJs version. That works fine but I must install three package with the NPM. For testing I installed it on the device manually with "npm install -global bower coffeescript gulp". Is there any way to do that in the yocto recipe so that the extra installation on the device is not necessary?! Thanks for all tipps and help!

BR Harald

Answer (score 1):

You could create recipes for npm packages you need and simply install them into the system: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-node-package-manager-npm-packages

I remember it was not working perfectly with older Yocto releases. With the most recent one (Dunfell) I had no problems with that.

Comment: I searched a little bit more but I dont find any working solution. I dont use the meta-node-js. We use a precompiled version with a self written recipe. But i am currently not able to install npm package like coffee-scripts within the bitbake build process. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: The link in the answer is now broken. The link to the Dunfell version is here: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.20/dev-manual/dev-manual-common-tasks.html?#creating-node-package-manager-npm-packages